# lambda aws failed to connect - connect ETIMEDOUT error to 2 external ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda

I have an issue in the past 3 days with 3% of the requests to our lambdas.

They fail due to connection timeout to other aws services. see stack trace in the same lambda init

```
2021-10-30T16:37:33.310Z    7954e15a-8ae7-491e-880b-f5b532bde961    INFO    TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to 
RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.4.211.23:443
    at /var/task/node_modules/cognito-express/lib/strategy.js:42:23
    at bound (domain.js:416:15)
    at runBound (domain.js:427:12)
    at tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:147:15)
    at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:129:24
```

```
2021-10-30T16:44:18.380Z    25392661-b635-4b73-9aed-67e655f13364    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "SequelizeConnectionError",
        "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
        "name": "SequelizeConnectionError",
        "parent": {
            "errorType": "Error",
            "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
            "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "syscall": "connect",
            "fatal": true,
            "stack": [
                "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT",
                "    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)",
                "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)",
                "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)"
            ]
        },
        "original": {
            "errorType": "Error",
            "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
            "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "syscall": "connect",
            "fatal": true,
            "stack": [
                "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT",
                "    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)",
                "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)",
                "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)"
            ]
        },
        "stack": [
            "SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT",
            "    at ConnectionManager.connect (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:126:17)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
            "    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:318:24)",
            "    at async /var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:250:32",
            "    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:280:7)",
            "    at async /var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:613:26",
            "    at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:953:12)",
            "    at async Function.findAll (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1753:21)",
            "    at async /var/task/src/routes/root/index_routes.js:20:18"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:412:35)",
        "    at process.emit (domain.js:470:12)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"
    ]
}
```

here is the mysql init code

```js
if (global.sequelize != null) {
  console.count('\x1b[32mRESERCH: connection exported from globals instead of creation\x1b[0m');
  module.exports = global.sequelize;
} else {
console.count('\x1b[31mRESERCH: new connection created\x1b[0m');
global.sequelize = new Sequelize(
    s.sqlDbName,
    s.sqlUsername,
    s.sqlPassword, {
    host: s.sqlDbHost,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    // to print out the query +  it's time
    // check if causes performance issues
    benchmark: true,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    }

});
```

It's only some of the requests but it's causing a lot of errors for our users.
couldn't detect the root cause.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: We also need more code and debugging details as there's 0 code in your question yet I can see you're using Sequelize. What DB are you using?

Comment: using mysql and Sequlize yeah. added the seqlize init code

Answer (score 1):

seems to be solved by changing the lambda's VPC slightly
it had 2 subnets, `public` and `private`.
removed the `public`

Not sure why it worked. maybe it forces the lambda to connect to db and cognito  from the internal ip

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me too... your answer gave me the confidence to go with a single subnet. I thought to do it but as lambda gives a minimum of two subnet recommendation, I didn't make changes at the subnet and killed 1 hour of extra time on it... :)